# Sketch app 3.3 exporting png with transparent background

Tags: export, png, sketch-app

I know this has been brought up before but it hasn't been resolved. I want to export a bunch of images which have a transparent background but maintain the dimensions of the transparent area. I've added a background and turned off the opacity but only the visible pixels are exportable.

Sketch has the most useless documentation about it http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/11-exporting/2-slices.html

I've tried converting them to slices and symbols but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution.

For instance there are several layers we want to export with transparent background:
[image]

Insert **Slice** around layers and check **Background Color** in inspector view:
[image]

Change **Alpha** of this background color to zero:
[image]

Then you can export Slice with the desired size and voila:
[image]

Comment: You can also use an artboard instead of a slice for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! Now slice function has a meaning, and a utility, for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Sketch template? Like the iOS UI template?

On the Symbols page, Sketch has put a rectangle behind and around all the artboards. If you have a transparent symbol on top of this, it (for some reason) exports the rectangle with it. Disable/delete the rectangle and you can export!